# What are the rules for the Kaph getting a dagesh at the end of the word?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

Specifically, in Naso 6:25, VeChuNe**Kah** while in the previous pasuk none of them have the dagesh as if often the case.  I presume it has something to do with the dagesh chazek in the nun.  How does this compare to Bereishis 49:25 in the Birchos Yaakov which have two words that have the Kaph with a dagesh at the end.  What are the rules?

Vi Ya-zi re KAH (Bereishis 49:25) vs. Vi Yeesh-Mi re CHAH (Bamidbar 6:24).

Any guidance on the rules?

Which rules of Dagesh Chazak are applying here?

Comment: The rules are the regular rules of dagesh chazak. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114185/759

Comment: Sorry.  I am wondering why those words even have a dagesh chazak at the end.  What rule of dagesh chazak is applying there that made the last letter get a dagesh.

Comment: I'm still confused. Do you know about dagesh chazak in general and find this case weird? Or are you just asking for all the rules of dagesh chazak and this example is completely arbitrary and not really relevant?

Comment: I know the rules for how to differentiate between them.  I am asking why there is a dagesh chazak there in the first place.  Simply, why isn't the word Ve'Chu'Ne'Chah?

Comment: That's not simpler. It's more ambiguous. For people to understand what to provide you they need to better understand what you're missing that leads you to ask why. Why questions can have lots of levels of answers depending who's asking (as any parent knows)